# Checkbox column is not sorted in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a row of check-boxes inside a vuetify data table.
I managed to do that but the sorting does not work on this column

I created this demo to demonstrate. [Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

I am using an array as a v-model and an id as a value as shown in docs. I expect that by sorting that column it will move the checked rows at the start or the end of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`custom-key-sort`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-custom-key-sort) for this, it is a prop on VDataTable and expects an object mapping column keys to sort functions:

```html
<v-data-table
  :custom-key-sort="{
    myCol: (a,b) => a - b
  }"
/>
```

There is one rather huge caveats to this (as of Vuetify 3.5.2): The sort function does not receive items directly, but only the values extracted by the key. If your column key does not correspond to a property on the item, the sort function will receive two `undefined` as args.

So basically, it will not work in your example, where the column key `select` is not a property. You will either have to make the selected value part of the items, or use `id` as column key.

Here is the [updated playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) using `id` as column key.

Btw. it looks like you are doing a lot to get custom row hover. Consider using a CSS class to simply things (see [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this code breaks sorting on other columns

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like it in the example, because the first column is inserted twice,  so the columns are shifted (i.e. thrid header sorts by fourth column). But that issue comes from your demo, not from `cusom-key-sort`. I have updated the playground where the issue is fixed. I also removed the multi-sort, as it confuses things. Do you still see the issue?

Comment: Sorry my fault. But anyway in your both playgrounds that you are created the sort button does not sort correctly. Cant attach an image in the comments but when sorting ascending it has gaps, when descending some of the checked rows are at the end and some at the beginning

Comment: Oh, indeed, when testing your claims, I removed the `custom-key-sort` and re-inserted it again at the wrong position. Please check the playgrounds again.

Comment: I tried to understand your code and found that there are a new property added to the v-table `sortRaw`  it receives the whole object
I used with the sorting code you provided and it worked, thanks
```
    const selectColumn = {
      key: 'select', sortRaw(a, b) {
        return isSelected(a.id) && !isSelected(b.id) ? -1 : 1
      }
    };
```

Comment: ```sortRaw(a, b) {
        if (isSelected(a.id) && !isSelected(b.id)) return -1
        if (!isSelected(a.id) && isSelected(b.id)) return 1
        return 0
      }```

with this code `multi-sort` also works!

Comment: Ah, interesting, I didn't know they brought back sorters on header level, that was a point of contention. Nice. Yes. `multi-sort` works with all approaches, I just removed it because I felt it convoluted the playground. Glad that it is working!